# How to extract XML with XSLT based on list index condition?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have a list `<segment>` that can occur from 2-4 times inside a `<list>`. How can I access the segments index-based for parsing them out as a `csv` string?

Example:

```
<root>
<list>
    <segment>
        <origin>new york</origin>
    </segment>
    <segment>
        <origin>san francisco</origin>
    </segment>
    <segment>
        <origin>London</origin>
    </segment>
    <segment>
        <origin>Berlin</origin>
    </segment>
</list>
<list>
    <segment>
        <origin>new york</origin>
    </segment>
    <segment>
        <origin>Berlin</origin>
    </segment>
</list>
</root>
```

My goal: extract the middle segments, or leave blank if none exists. The desired output would be:

```
sanfrancisco;london //both segments 2 + 3 filled
'';''               //both segments 2 + 3 empty
```

So the first and last segment should always be ignored. All segments in between should extract the `<origin>` tag. If there are no segments in between, and empty field should be added.

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="//list//segment">
        <!-- of course this is wrong, because it selects just all origins. -->
        <xsl:value-of select=".//origin" separator=";"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Question: how can I translate the following into xslt (pseudocode):

```
if (segment.size <= 2) write '';''
if (segment.size <= 3) write segment[1].origin;''
if (segment.size <= 4) write segment[1].origin;segment[2].origin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't have the logic about ignoring the first and last segments, you should actually do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//list">
    <xsl:value-of select="segment/origin" separator=";"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

To ignore the first and last ones, but not yet add in blank entries, you would do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//list">
    <xsl:value-of select="segment[not(position() = (1, last()))]/origin" separator=";"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

To add in blank entries, assuming there are indeed no more than 4 segments per list, do this...

```
<xsl:variable name="blank" select='"&apos;&apos;"' />
<xsl:for-each select="//list">
    <xsl:value-of select="(segment[not(position() = (1, last()))]/origin, $blank, $blank)[position() le 2]" separator=";"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What is the last `[position() le 2]` for? Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: The expression `(segment[not(position() = (1, last()))]/origin, $blank, $blank)` selects all `origin` elements (except the first and last), plus two blank strings, so may return up to 4 items. If there are just 3 `origin` elements in all, this expression returns 3 items (The middle `origin` plus two blank strings). But you only want two items per row in your CSV, so it just gets the first two in this list. (`le` means "less than or equal" by the way).